# Oracle and Pagination

Tags: oracle, hibernate, oracle10g, pagination, top-n

In MySql, the concept of pagination can easily be implemented with a single SQL statement using the `LIMIT` clause something like the following.

```
SELECT country_id, country_name 
FROM country c 
ORDER BY country_id DESC 
LIMIT 4, 5;
```

It would retrieve the rows starting from `5` to `10` in the result set which the SQL query retrieves.

---

In Oracle, the same thing can be achieved using *row numbers* with a subquery making the task somewhat tedious as follows.

```
SELECT country_id, country_name
FROM
  (SELECT rownum as row_num, country_id, country_name
   FROM
    (SELECT country_id, country_name
     FROM country
     ORDER BY country_id desc)
  WHERE rownum <= 10
  )
WHERE row_num >=5;
```

In Oracle 10g (or higher, I'm not sure about the higher versions though), this can be made somewhat easy such as,

```
SELECT country_id, country_name
  FROM (SELECT country_id, country_name, row_number() over (order by country_id desc) rank
      FROM country)
 WHERE rank BETWEEN 6 AND 10;
```

---

Regarding an application like a web application, the concept of pagination is required to implement almost everywhere and writing such SQL statements every time a (select) query is executed is sometimes a tedious job.

Suppose, I have a web application using Java. If I use the Hibernate framework then there is a direct way to do so using some methods supported by Hibernate like,

```
List<Country>countryList=session.createQuery("from Country order by countryId desc")
.setFirstResult(4).setMaxResults(5).list();
```

but when I simply use JDBC connectivity with Oracle like,

```
String connectionURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").newInstance();
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root");
statement = connection.createStatement();
rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * from country");
```

My question in this case, is there a precise way to retrieve a specified range of rows using this code? Like in the preceding case using the methods something like `setFirstResult()` and `setMaxResults()`? or the only way to achieve this is by using those subqueries as specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because 'No' is an answer too:

Unfortunately, you will have to use the subquery approach. I would personally use the one with the rank (the second one).