# Take() get all the rows in the table using Entity Framework (when querying a view)

Tags: sql, .net, performance, entity-framework, view

I'm getting the following behavior: I have a view that wrap some messy and legacy code and I want to get paged results of this view.

Normally, using the following code would work:

```
var itens = dbContext.Item.OrderBy(x => x.Id)
            .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ToList();
```

But EF generates this SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Code] AS [Code], 
    [Extent1].[SubGroupCode] AS [SubGroupCode]
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         [Item].[Id] AS [Id], 
         [Item].[Code] AS [Code], 
         [Item].[SubGroupCode] AS [SubGroupCode]
     FROM 
         [dbo].[Item] AS [Item]) AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY 
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC)
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

This seems to return all the rows and then get the 20 desired rows.

Doing the follow SQL return all the records in the same time (47s)

```
Select * Item
```

Putting a TOP 20 makes the query runs immediately.

I can't change the view, but I think this would be unnecessary.

I'm thinking in a better solution than just running a raw SQL or create a procedure to return the values...

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I have made some changes and tests. They don't resolve my problem, but i think that will help to understand it.

Using lambda values for the parameters the code looked like this:

```
var itens = dbContext.Item.OrderBy(x => x.Id)
                    .Take(() => pageSize)
                    .Skip(() => pageQty);
```

And I get this SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Limit1].[Code] AS [Code]
FROM ( 
    SELECT TOP (@p__linq__0) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Code] AS [Code]
    FROM (
        SELECT 
        [Item].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Item].[Code] AS [Code]
        FROM [dbo].[Item] AS [Item]) AS [Extent1]
        ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC
    )  AS [Limit1]
ORDER BY row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Limit1].[Id] ASC)
OFFSET @p__linq__1 ROWS
```

The performance issue still happening, but if run the SQL using the TOP statement in the first level, i get a immediate response. SQL:

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0 INT = 20
DECLARE @p__linq__1 INT = 0

SELECT 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Limit1].[Code] AS [Code]
FROM ( 
    SELECT TOP (@p__linq__0) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Code] AS [Code]
    FROM (
        SELECT **TOP (@p__linq__0)**  
        [Item].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Item].[Code] AS [Code]
        FROM [dbo].[Item] AS [Item]) AS [Extent1]
        ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC
    )  AS [Limit1]
ORDER BY row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Limit1].[Id] ASC)
OFFSET @p__linq__1 ROWS
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle query results pagination without TABLE FULL SCAN data access method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232846/oracle-query-results-pagination-without-table-full-scan-data-access-method)

Comment: i'm using SQL Server and EF, not hibernate. Even though, the suggestions did not helped to solve the problem...

Comment: Keep in mind adding the SELECT TOP in the inner query would always only end up returning the first page of results, leaving nothing to offset in the outer select. given your response, DISTINCT would likely be a culprit with execution inefficiencies when attempting to do the pagination. 9 times out of 10, the use of DISTINCT in a query/view is an act of desperation/laziness by developers to resolve Cartesian artifacts or similar query issues from loose joins.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

In the end, my view had a DISTINCT statement and this was causing the performance issue.

The strange part about that is that when i used the TOP 20 statement, it worked fine.

But removing the DISTINCT resolved the problem.

Thanks!